# Why was the design decision made to have an account name and then under it 2 types of keys (active and owner)?

Tags: accounts, account-name, active-key, owner-key

What is the reasoning for the setup of having an account name that is linked to 2 types of keys (owner and active)? What is the design decision for this and how does it compare to other blockchain setups like Ethereum and Bitcoin variants?